# Change vertical nav to horizontal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I have an unordered list acting as my navigation on a one page website sorted by sections. These sections or panels are full width and height of the browser window.

In the first panel, this list is vertical but when the user scrolls down the page to section two (i.e. the second panel from the top of the browser window) I'd like to change the style of it so that it fixes to the top of the browser window and becomes a horizontal nav instead of a vertical one. I don't want to duplicate the list if possible.

I'm not great at jQuery and don't really know where to start. Any help would be great.

This is my current code that gets the width and height of the browser window and displays a full screen div:

```
function fitElements(){
var height=$(window).height();
var width=$(window).width();
$('.panel').css('height',height);
$('.panel').css('width',width)
};
```

Comment: Can you post some code (jsFiddle) of everything you have so far?

Comment: So, to clarify, what you basically have is a side nav bar and you want this navigation bar to follow as your user scrolls down the page, right (only horizontally)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple example:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgLek/)

**html**:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" id="linkOne">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="linkTwo">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="linkThree">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="divOne" class="panel">    
</div>
<div id="divTwo" class="panel">    
</div>
<div id="divThree" class="panel">    
</div>
```

**css**:

```
#nav {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:10px;     
}

#nav.horizontal li {
  float:left;
}

#divOne {
 background-color:#cef;   
}
#divTwo{
 background-color:#efc;   
}
#divThree{
 background-color:#fce;   
}
```

​
**js/jQuery**:

```
$("div.panel").css({
    height: $(window).height(),
    width: $(window).width()
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    ($("#divTwo").offset().top <= window.pageYOffset) ? $("#nav").addClass("horizontal") : $("#nav").removeClass("horizontal");
});

$("#linkOne").click(function(e){
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divOne").offset().top
    });
    $("#nav").removeClass("horizontal");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#linkTwo").click(function(e){
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divTwo").offset().top
    });
    $("#nav").addClass("horizontal");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#linkThree").click(function(e){
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#divThree").offset().top
    });
    $("#nav").addClass("horizontal");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

​

Comment: Good solution, but please don't use `return false`. Take a look at this article: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: @kei: I don't think that's going to help him very much, considering he said he's a jQuery novice and he would have to basically his idea from scratch. All you just did was illustrate the fundamental idea of what he wants to do (make a vertical list horizontal) without any of the effects, movements, or anything. Plus, if he goes that route, it's going to look terrible because he doesn't have the jQuery skills yet to smooth out the effects, even if he can get it working.

Comment: Good solution, but according to the question it needs one little correction - from onclick to onscroll: http://jsfiddle.net/bbYZS/2/

Comment: @Bram: Noted (and updated).
(@)Zach: "I don't think that's going to help him very much" Well, that's for him to decide now, isn't it?
(@)Stano: Updated (to respond to both).

Comment: This is great and works a treat. Out of curiosity, so I can learn, why is there click functions for each navigation link?

Comment: @egr103: You don't have to. You could have one click handler for all and have the logic inside it. I simple made it separate because it's simpler to understand. Here's the updated code with only one event handler for the nav: http://jsfiddle.net/qWjZM/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, providing I understood you correctly (see my comment looking for clarification), your goal is to make sure that your navigation pane is visible to your site visitors even when they scroll down the page. I would caution you against changing the nav bar to show horizontally after reaching a certain point on the page only because it will look pretty choppy, especially in slower browsers, unless (and sometimes even if) you provide a lot more code (complex for a novice) to smooth out the transition.

What I suggest is that you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705855/floating-div-content-that-tracks-along-a-parent-divs-height/11705971) from a few days ago. I created a demo for the effect that he was looking for, which is very similar to what you are looking for, and hosted it on my development site. Take a look and if it's something that you like and if it is and you have trouble implementing it let me know and I'll be more than happy to help you.